# print specific number of lines after matching pattern

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I have to print 81 lines after each occurrence of the expression "AAA" from my input file. How do I go about that?

Comment: Search for "awk one liners". That should help.

Answer (score 20):

The following idioms describe how to select a range of records given
a specific pattern to match:

a) Print all records from some pattern:

```
awk '/pattern/{f=1}f' file
```

b) Print all records after some pattern:

```
awk 'f;/pattern/{f=1}' file
```

c) Print the Nth record after some pattern:

```
awk 'c&&!--c;/pattern/{c=N}' file
```

d) Print every record except the Nth record after some pattern:

```
awk 'c&&!--c{next}/pattern/{c=N}1' file
```

e) Print the N records after some pattern:

```
awk 'c&&c--;/pattern/{c=N}' file
```

f) Print every record except the N records after some pattern:

```
awk 'c&&c--{next}/pattern/{c=N}1' file
```

g) Print the N records from some pattern:

```
awk '/pattern/{c=N}c&&c--' file
```

I changed the variable name from "f" for "found" to "c" for "count" where
appropriate as that's more expressive of what the variable actually IS.

So, you'd want "e" above:

```
awk 'c&&c--;/AAA/{c=81}' file
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a pretty straightforward way to do this with grep:

```
grep -A 81 AAA input_file
```

From the man page:

> -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
>   Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.  Places a line containing  a  group  separator (--)  between  contiguous  groups of matches.  With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

Answer (score 6):

Add `{c=81;next}c-->0` after your expression:

```
awk '/AAA/{c=81;next}c-->0' somefile
```

Answer (score 5):

To print the matching line **and** the following 81 lines:

```
awk '/AAA/{x=NR+81}(NR<=x){print}' input_file
```

To print the following 81 lines but **not** the matching line:

```
awk '/AAA/{x=NR+81;next}(NR<=x){print}' input_file
```

Answer (score 4):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed /AAA/,+81!d file
```