# How to print 2 consecutive lines after a pattern in file using awk and the matched line itself

Tags: regex, awk

In a text file as following,

```
####PATTERN#######
#Line1
#Line2
#Line3
#Line4
####PATTERN#######
#Line1
#Line2
#Line3
#Line4
#Line5
####PATTERN#######
#Line1
#Line2
#Line3
#Line4
```

I would like to extract the matched line and the next 2 lines. the output should be:

```
####PATTERN#######
#Line1
#Line2
####PATTERN#######
#Line1
#Line2
####PATTERN#######
#Line1
#Line2
```

How to achieve this?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: You don't need awk for this. Use `grep -A 2` to print the 2 lines after the match.

Comment: See http://awk.info/?OneLiners

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283567/print-specific-number-of-lines-after-matching-pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`, as requested

```
awk '/PATTERN/{c=3}c&&c--' file
```

or

```
awk '/PATTERN/{c=3}c-->0' file
```

But it's easier with `grep`:

```
grep -A2 file
```

Comment: What do these awk codes mean? The `c=3`, and `c&&c--` and `c-->0`? It would be really helpful to be able to learn how they work

Comment: @xen Those are just standard operations. `c = 3` assigns 3 to the variable `c`; `c` && c--` fist interprets `c` as a boolean (false if zero, true otherwise) and if true decrements `c` but returns the original value. `c --> 0` is just a fancy and somewhat misleading way of writing `(c--) > 0`, so will always decrement `c` and return true if and only if `c` was greater than `0` before decrementing.  In both cases, since they are outside of a code block (`{...}`), they are a condition; since they don't have an explicit block attached they control the default action, which is to print the line.

Answer (score 2):

Use this awk:

```
awk '/PATTERN/{s=1} s++ < 4' file

####PATTERN#######
#Line1
#Line2
####PATTERN#######
#Line1
#Line2
####PATTERN#######
#Line1
#Line2
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a straightforward way to do this using grep. You will get `--` lines between your context, and can use an inverted match `-v` to remove them. See the documentation from the grep [`man page`](http://www.ss64.com/bash/grep.html).

```
grep -A2 "PATTERN" file | grep -v -- "^--$"
```

Using awk:

```
awk '/PATTERN/{c=NR+2}(NR<=c){print}' file
```

Using sed:

```
sed '/PATTERN/,+2!d' file
```

Perl one-liner

```
perl -ne 'print if (/PATTERN/ and $p=2) .. not $p--' file
```

Comment: To get rid of the group separator, you can also use `grep --no-group-separator -A2 ...`