# How can I find lines before my match if my grep doesn't support the -B option?

Tags: unix, grep

I need to view 5 line before grep output.
I used the command,

```
grep -B 5 pattern filename
```

But was thrown with the error `/usr/bin/grep: illegal option --B`

How to handle this situation and to view 5 lines before grep statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [grep a file, but show several surrounding lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081/grep-a-file-but-show-several-surrounding-lines)

Comment: Sounds like your grep doesn't support that option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [print specific number of lines after matching pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283567/print-specific-number-of-lines-after-matching-pattern) To get the `-B` behaviour, just use `tac` before (print in reverse) and `tac` again once done.

Comment: You could install a different version of grep, or you could install [ack](http://beyondgrep.com) which is a greplike tool that supports -A, -B and -C just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `awk`?

If it is a viable option, check this one, long, line:

```
$ awk '/PATTERN/{for(i=1;i<=x;)print a[i++];print}{for(i=1;i<x;i++)a[i]=a[i+1];a[x]=$0;}' x=5 file
```

The above command will return the five lines before the matched pattern and the matched pattern (i.e. 6 lines in total whereas `grep -B 5` returns five lines in total including the matched one).

`x` designates the number of lines

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You Simply me:) This works. I would like to understand the concept hidden in it. I understod the first for loop, but the second for loop, I couldnt get hold of it. Can you please explain the concept in it?   {for(i=1;i<x;i++)a[i]=a[i+1];a[x]=$0;}

Comment: @Sadhun Great! you can refer to `awk` for loop user guide [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/For-Statement.html) , simply put `a` is the array that stores all of the elements, the first loop prints, and for the second loop I'll give you a hint, try adding `print a[i+1]` after `a[x]=$0` and play around with the loop. Should be a learning experience as well :-) Lastly, if you can choose my answer as the answer for this question it'll be great.

Answer (score 0):

Simply_Me's answer is correct but copies all previous lines on each non-match. (nit picking technicality: even if gawk's implementation avoids copying the strings themselves it still would have to re-hash the index). So, still sticking with awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { cl=1; }

/foo5/ {
    for (i=cl; i<cl+N; i++)
    print pLines[i % N];
    cl=1;
}

{  pLines[cl % N] = $0; cl = cl + 1; }
```

cl stands for current line. If we have a match we print N lines we stored in pLines array before. You may wish to print the pattern itself, which I didnt. Regardless of seeing the pattern, we store the line we just processed in pLines with the % operator, so we do not have to shift the array.

For

```
zoo0
blah1
foo2
bar3
hehe4
lisp5
foo5
blah6
foo7
bar8
hehe9
foo5
```

This prints

```
blah1
foo2
bar3
hehe4
lisp5
foo5
blah6
foo7
bar8
hehe9
```

which is the previous 5 lines not including the pattern.

It also works reasonably on

```
hehe4
lisp5
foo5
blah6
foo7
bar8
hehe9
foo5
```

where there is no 5 previous line before the first match of foo5. In this case it prints empty lines. You may need to tailor that for your needs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I tested the script several times, and it does print 5 lines before the matched pattern. Pls double check your script when running it. 
`$ grep -B 5 mango 5before.txt
apples
oranges
grapes
mango
orcl
msft
nugt
dust
mango`
`$ awk '/mango/{for(i=1;i<=x;)print a[i++];print}{for(i=1;i<x;i++)a[i]=a[i+1];a[x]=$0;}' x=4 5before.txt

apples
oranges
grapes
mango
orcl
msft
nugt
dust
mango`

Only addition, as you mentioned, is in the case where the matched pattern is less than 5 lines from beginning of the file the script will print an empty line.

Comment: I apologise for misreading the solution and will edit the corresponding comment. I saw the pattern and thought everything afterwards belongs to it. Nevertheless, it shifts the array meaning on every non-match it moves the element at index N to index N-1: gawk's hash table (or is it a balanced tree?) implementation of arrays will not like that once you increase N to a few hundred or start moving around very long lines. BTW, I didn't down vote your solution, just consider mine nicer :).

Comment: thank you for editing the original comment and the info regarding the hash table.